# Is it possible for a mac app to edit the hosts file without asking the the super user's password?

Tags: macos, hosts

I am planning a OS X app that involves editing the hosts file regularly. I would think this would be very annoying for the user if it asks for the super user's password. Is it technically possible to input the password thru code or maybe modify the property of the hosts file to allow the app to modify it while its installed?

Comment: You should probably be using NetInfo rather than the hosts file.

Comment: @Paul R: Hasn't NetInfo been deprecated for a couple of versions now?

Comment: @Chuck: I thought it was just the command line tools like `nicl` that had been deprecated - you have to use `dscl` *et al* now instead ? Maybe it's a different underlying technology too now though ? I'm a little out of touch...

Comment: It´s not annoying for the user, it´s a security measure. A user should be informed every time such a fundamental file is being edited by any application and storing a password to get permanent root access is a bit dodgy.

Comment: @Paul R: It's hard to find solid sources, and my recollection of the original documents I read has faded into the past. Here's one from random Googling: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2006/03/3178.ars

Comment: @Chuck: thanks for the link - it looks like NetInfo may well have been superseded then - either way though, I think the OP should probably not be messing with the hosts file but should be using the appropriate API *du jour* instead.

Comment: @Paul R: Sorry to spam your timeline. In case you or anyone reading later is interested, I found the document I was thinking of (or at least one very similar to it) that says NetInfo is deprecated: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/additionalfeatures/additionalfeatures.html

Comment: @Chuck: thanks - looks like Open Directory is the new NetInfo...

Comment: @paul r. Is it possible to re-route all http request to a local html file thru the API?

Comment: @Eric: Presumably you mean outgoing HTTP requests ? I would guess that you might be able to use the Open Directory API in the same way as a you would have used a hosts file in simpler times, so that everything goes to localhost, but I have no idea what the implications would be for other types of TCP/IP traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, No, the hosts file requires root access.